# how to set aria-readonly to false for a table using jquery? i want to wrap the <td> inside <span> in document.rady function

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, yui, yahoo

Below code is copied from the chrome developer console , i want to enclose each td inside a span programmatically . i tried many was . i think aria-readonly atrribute of table is preventing me to wrap the td in document.ready function.

```
<table class="yui3-calendar-grid" id="calendaryui_3_18_1_1_1595846986681_15_pane_0" role="grid" **aria-readonly="true"** aria-label="July 2020" tabindex="1"></table>
```

Comment: `$('table').attr('aria-readonly', 'false');` or `$('table').prop('aria-readonly', 'false');`

Comment: solved the issue by putting the the code in window.load